# Can a woman uncover her hair for the sake of employment?

Tags: halacha, women, employment, hair-covering

I am aware of many *poseqim* who hold that in order to get and hold a job, it is permissible for men to remove their *kippoth* during the interview and their workday.

Can a woman who badly needs employment do the same thing and uncover her hair? Why or why not?

Comment: I highly doubt it. Hair covering is an arguably _d'oraita_ requirement. Wearing a kippa is a minhag.

Comment: It should be noted that in most western countries AFAIK it is illegal to refuse to hire a person because he wears a kippa or she cover her hair for religious reasons, so this question is probably moot.

Comment: Almost no one holds that *kisui rosh le-nashim* is *de-oraitha*. Most hold it is an *asmakhta be-alma*. And as far as it being illegal, not sure if you live in Western world, but people are turned down for employment all the time due to a myriad of religous observances. They are also fired and threatened with their jobs for them. I have had both happen to me. This is real, same as the *kippah* question for men.

Comment: @Daniel, as this is one of the most difficult forms of discrimination to prove, the question is certainly not moot.

Comment: Just note that wigs exist which look almost exactly like natural hair. Many a working woman covers her hair without her employer’s knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking this question in terms of actual practice, then you should direct your question to your local, qualified Rav. The specifics of your situation would determine your practice.

If you are asking is it possible for a woman to be permitted, the short answer is yes. The details of the reasoning behind the decision are found in Igrot Moshe, Volume 3, Even HaEzer, section 1, Siman 57. In keeping with the wishes of the author, Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, not to translate his responsa, you will need to look at the actual letter for details.

It's worth pointing out that this ruling by Rabbi Feinstein is considered very lenient in many circles. Details can be found in English in Halichos Bas Yisrael, volume 1, chapter 5, halacha 5 on page 86, note 9.

Another point worth noting is that according to many, the concept of a woman covering her hair is likely not restricted to married women. It may also apply to unmarried women who have had sexual relations outside of marriage. This is discussed in the responsa of Tzitz Eliezer, volume 15, Siman 55.

Comment: Actually, this *teshuvah* of Rav Feinstein z"l is concerning a widow who needs to uncover her hair in the face of pressing financial loss due to employment issues. It appears that Rav Feinstein makes a distinction between married women and widows in the obligation to cover their hair, the former being "*de-oraytha*" (which either indicates that specific case to which the *pasuq* refers, or most likely the extension of the [mistaken, respectfully] understanding of the *Tosafoth* and their reading of this term in the *gemara*). Only at the end does he mention as another *ssad lehaqel* that...

Comment: ...perhaps haircovering for women is dependent upon local *minhagh* and may therefore be relaxed in time of need in a locale where they do not generally cover. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist: Yes, the particular teshuvah is dealing with a widow. In context, it would be applicable to married Jewish women whose husband was unable to support them and they were faced with the same financial loss test. And it's also important to point out that it doesn't eliminate the requirement to cover when in public, only while at work.

Comment: You can only say that it would likewise apply to married women if you are either: [a] Rav Feinstein himself, or [b] a *poseq* in your own right who is making his own determination. Rav Feinstein makes his distinction regarding widows by specifically mentioning that married women (in his view) do not have the same latitude. You cannot simply draw lines with a crayon like a matching game. If he wasn't asked the *she'elah* specifically, then his *teshuvah* cannot be used as a basis for it at all. Perhaps as an opening for thinking in that direction, but not through direct "application". Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist: Did you see the first paragraph in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but you then went on to make the determination yourself. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist, did you read the second paragraph as well?

Comment: As pointed out in the comment, your second paragraph is misleading. Although you refer the reader to read the responsum itself, it is very clear he is restricting his ruling to someone who is no longer married; not someone presently married. Your last paragraph also seems irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @robev why are you assuming this is a man asking the question? My assumption was the individual positing the question may actually be a married woman and that is the reason for directing them to their LOR. The question itself is very open & sounds like are there any circumstances where it may be permissible. According to some, like Reb Moshe, there are conditions where it is possible. That’s honest, not misleading.

Comment: I didn't assume a man was asking the question. And Rav Moshe's circumstances preclude a presently married woman, which is the subject of this question.